# Creating a PostgreSql trigger to update stock Quantity

Tags: java, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I want to create a trigger for an inventory management system, that use Postgresql DBMS Version 9.4.
It permit, me to calculate quantity of product in stock.So, her is the schema of the tables we need.

```
produit(produitid(PK),qteInitiale,qteInStock,prixDachat,prixDevente) ; 
entreeDetaille(qteIn,prixDachat,remise,(produitId(FK),bonId(FK),(PK)));
sortieDetaille(qteOut,prixDeVente,remise,(produitId(FK),bonId(FK),(PK)));

The Stock quantity = produit.qteInitiale where id = ? + sum(qteIn) where  id = ? + sum(qteOut) where id = ?
```

The trigger need to be call after an insert event occured on entreeDetaille or sortieDetaille tables.

I have Started with this try, but is not working for me :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateqteinstock()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    declare 
    qteInitiale money;
    qteAcheter money ;
    qteVendue money;
    qteEnStock money ; 
    produitID integer ;
    begin

    if TG_OP == "INSERT" then   
    produitID := NEW.produitid; 
    else
    produitID := OLD.produitid; 
    end if ;


    -- ramener la quantité Initiale de stock
    qteInitiale := select qteinitiale from produit where produitid = produitID ;

    -- ramener la quantité acheter
    qteAcheter := (select sum(qtein) from entreedetaille where produitid = produitID ); 

 -- ramener la quantité vendue
   qteVendue := select sum(qteOut) from sortieDetaille where produitid = produitID ; 

    -- calculate quantité qte en stock + quantité acheter + quantité vendue
    qteEnStock := qteInitiale + qteAcheter - qteVendue;

    -- update la quantite en stock ;
    update produit set qtestock = qteEnStock where produitid = produitID ; 

    if TG_OP == "INSERT" 
    return new;
    else 
    return old;
    end;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I have received this error :

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "produitid" does not exist
  Où : PL/pgSQL function updateqteinstock() line 11 at assignment
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
    at DAO.BonDachatDAO.create(BonDachatDAO.java:203)
    at CONTROLLER.BonDachatController.createBonDachat(BonDachatController.java:83)
    at VIEW.eventsManagers.BonDachatEventManager.saveBonDachat(BonDachatEventManager.java:108)
    at VIEW.eventsManagers.BonDachatEventManager.actionPerformed(BonDachatEventManager.java:79)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "porduitid" does not exist
  Où : PL/pgSQL function updateqteinstock() line 14 at assignment
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
    at DAO.BonDachatDAO.create(BonDachatDAO.java:203)
    at CONTROLLER.BonDachatController.createBonDachat(BonDachatController.java:83)
    at VIEW.eventsManagers.BonDachatEventManager.saveBonDachat(BonDachatEventManager.java:108)
    at VIEW.eventsManagers.BonDachatEventManager.actionPerformed(BonDachatEventManager.java:79)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here where i have attached the triggers to this procedure:

```
CREATE TRIGGER achatTrigger AFTER INSERT OR DELETE on entreedetaille
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateqteinstock();



CREATE TRIGGER venteTrigger AFTER INSERT OR DELETE on sortiedetaille
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE updateqteinstock();
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need start ( and end ) when set select value to qteInitiale variable.

Change like this :

```
qteInitiale := (select qteinitiale from produit where produitid = produitID) ;
```

Comment: Or use `select qteinitiale into qteInitiale  from produit ...`

Comment: affter fix the last error , i got this error : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "INSERT" does not exist
  Où : PL/pgSQL function updateqteinstock() line 10 at IF

Comment: use ' single quote instead of ".

Comment: I don't know, but he don't accepts qteInitiale := assignement        org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column reference "qteinitiale" is ambiguous
  Détail : It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
  Où : PL/pgSQL function updateqteinstock() line 18 at assignment